run Playwright tests on google chrome: channel is set to chrome in playwright.config.js
I am a Playwright beginner. Our test application runs only on chrome. If user tries to run our application on any other browser, our application displays a message to run it on chrome. I am trying to run a login test case that I have scripted, but the Playwright UI opens the testcase in chromium and when it loads our test application(page.goto), the test application displays the message to run it on chrome. How can I get playwright to run on chrome? I have already specified the channel as chrome in playwright.config.js
The screenshot displays how chromium is launched the minute I do npx playwright test --ui.
This is in the playwright.config.js:
 /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
   // {
     // name: 'chromium',
     // use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
   // },

   // {
   //   name: 'firefox',
    //  use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
   // },

    //{
     // name: 'webkit',
    //  use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
   // },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
     {
       name: 'Google Chrome',
       use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
     },


  ],

This is how I am running the testcase, from terminal:
npx playwright test --ui

This is the login.spec.js:
import {test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
//import { LoginPage } from '../pages/LoginPage';
import LoginPage from '../pages/LoginPage';


test('Login to ABCD', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://abcd/auth/login');
  const myLogin = new LoginPage(page);
  await myLogin.logintoABCD();
});

enter image description here

Did you try running tests on different browsers? npx playwright test --project "Google Chrome"?

Hi! My test did run! So it wasn't running with the npx playwright test --ui  , the test application would open and display the message that the application runs only on chrome. So I did not know that the gui mode is different from the headed mode.  And so I tried this npx playwright test homePageTest.spec.js --headed and I think its running fine with it, but its too fast, so now I am learning how to slow it down! Thanks a lot @ggorlen
